# Accessing the current color of a color series

Tags: color

The [`xcolor`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) documentation clearly states that `\color{foo}` (or similar commands) should access the current color of the (previously defined) color series `foo`. However, the following MWE produces a black square for me instead of the expected blue one.

Is this a bug? Am I doing anything wrong?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\definecolorseries{foo}{rgb}{last}{blue}{red}
\resetcolorseries{foo}

\textcolor{foo}{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The slightly awkward syntax `foo!!` does what `foo` should do and can be used as a workaround.

I have investigated a bit further and discovered that the internal representation of the color (`\\color@foo`) is

```latex
\xcolor@{}{}{rgb}{0,0,1}
```

with an empty second argument, while other colors have some driver specific specification there. I strongly suspect this to be a bug and will report it as such.